# jQuery replace text up to first instance of dollar sign

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, html-select

I have got a number of shipping options and I have code to calculate them.  However, I need a way to replace all instances of the words (aka strip out) so i'm just left with the numbers (price).

```
<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="103">In-store Pickup </option>
<option value="701">UPS Ground $9.90 </option>
<option value="703">UPS 3Day Select® $30.88 </option>
</select>
```

So I want to strip everything from option value 701 so I am just left with 9.90.  I also want the same thing to happen for value 703 so I am just left with 30.88, instead of writing a function for each.  Currently I only have a function for option value 701, but I want it dynamic, can it be done..probably with regex which im no good at?

```
$("option:selected").each(function () { 
var isthePrice = $(this).text().replace("UPS Ground $", ""); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace everything (`.` means any character, `*` means "match zero or more times")  followed by a `$` (but in regex the `$` is a special character so you have to escape it with the `\`):

```
var isthePrice = $(this).text().replace(/.*\$/, '');
```

Comment: There is no indication from the OP that he wants to do anything special with that option.  But you're right that it won't match because there is no `$` there.

Comment: as for above post. I can just add this in an `If` statement that will yield only if the option contains a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$("option:selected").each(function () { 
    var isthePrice = $(this).text().replace(/^[^$]*/, "");
}
```